# Data Exchange WCF and Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am using a WCF service and a Silverlight Client sending data to the service.

I am sending data to the service in a For-Loop.

However, when the loop runs for the first time the data is being perfectly run, while in the next turn it is returning this error:

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at WcfConsumption.SimpleSVC.SetXMLCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at WcfConsumption.MainPage.proxy_SetXMLCompleted(Object sender, SetXMLCompletedEventArgs e)
   at WcfConsumption.SimpleSVC.SimpleWCFClient.OnSetXMLCompleted(Object state)**

In the service, I am storing the received file in a XML file.

Comment: @Jayesh: Why not look at the InnerException like it indicates?  What does *that* exception message say?

Comment: Are you sure that the service is not throwing an exception?
Do you know if the second call reaches your code in the service?
Try debugging the server side. The most simple thing is to dump a log file in each call.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying.
Well after some debugging and after reading some blogs I found that the error was not in the service but in my method.
And this error is usually thrown not because of an error in the WCF service.

Well, this solved and I got one more error :(
When I am sending small sized data in the loop, the data is being perfectly sent, however If i send one large sized data in the iteration, the service is throwing an exception ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your follow up comment - check the values you have got set in your binding configuration on the server side. Pay attention to attributes like `maxBufferSize` and `maxReceivedMessageSize` on the binding, and attributes like `maxStringContentLength` and `maxBytesPerRead` on the `readerQuotas` node of the binding.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/retrieving-huge-amount-of-data-from-wcf-service-in-silverlight-application/.